# Is there a nodejs/system bandwith limit for handling many GET requests through a socket?

Tags: node.js, networking, io, limit, throughput

I have a node js script running that pumps data through a socket (the server responds to many small http get requests) and for some reason the bandwith gets limited to 1MB/s (sometimes less than 1MB/s but never faster). I there a system setting for this or a nodejs config param that needs to be tweaked?

I have this issue on different machines (with more and less RAM) localhost - localhost and external - localhost, a screenshot from tcptrack here:

[1MB/s limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sToB9.png)